# Transaction is visible on Ethereum blockchain explorer, but token is not displayed in Metamask wallet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I am playing with Ethereum smart contracts and noticed some strange behavior of some transactions.
Transaction is visible and it states that tokens are sent to an address but when I check balance on Metamask it's not here (Token contract is added to MetaMask). What could be the reason of such contract behavior?

This is example transaction: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xf3316c497fd47ee79be57be7b91cb96cc0414003a155d8ff8bc83b3a090594c9
200,000 tokens is sent to https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9DEF8C013eb590aFf09c8c76F9A74A3055fAA177#tokentxns and it's displayed on ropsten network explorer, but I can't see them or manipulate on MetaMask.

This is part of my smart contract which does transfer, I marked line with comment "invisible" which does not work for me:

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
  require(value <= _balances[msg.sender]);
  require(to != address(0));

  uint256 tokensToBurn = findOnePercent(value);
  uint256 tokensToStack = findOnePercent(value);
  uint256 tokenstoDeduct = tokensToBurn.add(tokensToStack);
  uint256 tokensToTransfer = value.sub(tokenstoDeduct);

  _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(value);
  _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(tokensToTransfer);

  _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(tokenstoDeduct);

  emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokensToTransfer); // visible on metaMask
  emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), tokensToBurn); // burned
  emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(VAULT_ADDRESS), tokensToStack); // invisible on metaMask
  return true;
}
```

This is screenshot of address wallet: 0x9DEF8C013eb590aFf09c8c76F9A74A3055fAA177
[image]

Please advise what I could do wrong here.

[meanwhile I submitted ticket to MetaMask, maybe it's a defect on wallet extension]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **contract** address to your Metamask instance.

1. In the account detail, click on "Add token"

   [image: In the account detail, click on "Add token"]
2. Paste the conctract address to the address field in the "Custom token" tab

   [image: Paste the conctract address to the address field in the "Custom token" tab]
3. Review the data, click "Next", and you you can see the token balance in your wallet.

   [image: Review the data, click "Next", and you you can see the token balance in your wallet.]

Comment: Hi Petr, token is added to the wallet and it's visible for other addresses. The issue is, that it's not visible for that Vault address. [Updated description]

Comment: When you say "not visible in Vault address" are you sure you have added the token on vault account?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yes, I am sure, I am updating description with screenshot of the wallet.

Comment: Worth to mention, that I tested this contract on two separate networks, Ropsten testnet and local Ganache network: both behaves the same and invisible in MetaMask but transaction exists

Comment: Sounds like a bug in MetaMask and you need to take it to their customer support

Comment: Thanks, I filed a ticket on metamask and another discussion here: https://community.metamask.io/t/extension-defect-tokens-balance-is-missing-in-metamask-wallet/765